# Normalizing hourly wind speed data

Tags: normalization

Can anyone suggest a best method to normalize a dataset containing hourly wind speeds. The issue with the data is that it has an excessive amount of zeros within its distribution so its a little difficult. I have tried boxcox transformation methods, the dubey method but these doesn't work too well. Is there any other method that I could try?

Comment: What kind of statistical analysis are you planning on doing after "normalizing" the data?

Comment: I am planning on using it to forecast using the arima and arma models. After normalizing, the periodicies within the data suppose to be more apparent. So i want visualize the periods. From reading reviews, they suggest normalizing the data firstly before implementing the forecasting models.

Comment: No amount of "normalizing" of any form is going to change the fact that you have a large number of values at one extreme of the range, which is the essential nature of the problem, nor will it affect your visualizations.  Asking to normalize therefore is not a useful question.  Consider reformulating your post to focus on what your problem actually is.